# Transfer file form FTP server to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, ftp, google-drive-api, ftp-client

I need a way to schedule a download from an FTP server to my Google Drive account. I need to get the file off of the FTP server to drive, so my [[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) can use its data. I know I can't use [[image]google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), to my knowledge it only can use `urlFetch()`.

I have found [MultCloud](https://www.multcloud.com) witch will do what I am asking, but I can't find the IP address of the server. This is crucial because the FTP server I am connecting to needs to white list the address.

So, is there a service that can transfer files from an FTP server to Google Drive? That provides its IP address, and preferably free?

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if a combination of an FTP client to schedule the download to your machine, and Google Drive for PC\Mac client to sync a folder up to your Google drive would work?  Again, I am not familiar with the use case, and was wondering if this would be an option for you?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know I can do that. I have a program that can pull form an FTP and then save it. But I would like to get away form relying on a computer to be on, and for internet connection of that computer to be good. What I need is a cloud service like Mover.io but cheaper.

Comment: Apps Script can use URL Fetch, but as far as socket connections, it does not have that.  There is another option, although it may cost...  it would involve setting up a GPC VM with really low specs to save on money, and running the process from the VM.  I believe the first $300 is free when you sign up, so you can at least test to see if the process will work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

According to their [Common Error Solutions](https://www.multcloud.com/help/solutions.html) page, the IP address which needs to be added to the firewall white list is:

```
209.126.103.1/19
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. If the needed information is only found via your link then this is considered to be "not an answer", because all relevant information is needed directly here, not only linked. Please read [answer] and take the [tour].

Comment: "I have found MultCloud witch will do what I am asking, but I can't find the IP address of the server. This is crucial because the FTP server I am connecting to needs to white list the address."

The IP address is 209.126.103.1/19 and can be found on their website.

Comment: I took the liberty to rephrase (more than usual for a normal edit, admittedly) your answer. I want to lead you towards clearer phrasing. Please feel free to adapt to your liking, but please try for similarily clear and a little more verbose version. If you feel this changes your voice please accept my apology, you are of course free to return to previous version and I promise to then let it be. Good luck.